# after implementing iNotifypropertychanged in ViewModel SelectedItem is not working on listview

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Hello I am using MVVM in Xamarin Forms. I am trying to Bind my Listview's SeletedItem to my ViewModel. I binded it and worked fine. but when i have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged to update the view for some other component it stopped working.

I want it to work even INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented in my ViewModel. I am figuring out the problem why its happened. I searched on internet and Xamarin's documentation and could not find the reason.

**My View**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonsList}"
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          SelectionMode="None"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="5">
                        <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" 
                           FontSize="Medium" 
                           TextColor="Orange"/>

                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**ViewModel**

```
 public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        PersonsList = new ObservableCollection<User>
        {
            new User(){ UserId = 1, FullName = "John" },
            new User(){ UserId = 2, FullName = "Alex" },
            new User(){ UserId = 3, FullName = "Ellen" },
            new User(){ UserId = 4, FullName = "Grace" }
        };
    }
    public ObservableCollection<User> PersonsList { get; set; }

    private User _selectedPerson { get; set; }
    public User SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return _selectedPerson; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedPerson != value)
            {
                _selectedPerson = value;
               OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Hope to get some useful advice.

Comment: none of your setters is calling PropertyChanged, so you're not really using INPC.

Comment: I updated my question. I have added the property change but still it do not detect Selected Item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `SelectedPerson` property to call `OnPropertyChanged()`.

```
private User _selectedPerson { get; set; }
public User SelectedPerson
{
    get { return _selectedPerson; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedPerson != value)
        {
            _selectedPerson = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question. I have added the property change but still it do not detect Selected Item.

Comment: Try explicitly setting `SelectionMode` to `Single`. Also, hook into `ItemTapped` and 'ItemSelected` to make sure that the `ListView` is actually registering selection. Are you seeing any UI changes when selecting an item?

Comment: Thanks @ottermatic it is working with SelectionMode to single but it is getting a selection color. I know a way to add a custom render to remove. Is it a way to get rid of that. The reason i used SelectionMode was this selection color.

Comment: There is no easy way to remove or change the selection color. you need to use a custom renderer or for android you need to set all these in your `styles.xml: 
<item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
  <item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewHighlighted</item>
  <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
  <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
  <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
`

Comment: you can see i use the same color for most of those. you can also immediately set `SelectedItem` to `null` to remove the highlighting immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your advice